Adding stochastic variables
I'm a student of industrial economics, and in the statistics introduction course I'm currently learning how to implement the central limit theorem.
From the textbook:

Assume $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$ are independent stochastic varibales,
where $X_i \in N(\mu_i ,\sigma_i)$, $i = 1,2, ... , n$  and $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ are given constants
Then
$\sum c_i  X_i \in N(\sum c_i  \mu_i , \sqrt{c_i^2  \sigma_i^2})$

I thought I could use this theorem to solve these two problems:
Problem 1.
$X$ and $Y$ are independent. $X\in N(3,4)$ and $Y\in N(1,3)$.
a) $3X + Y$
Problem 2.
Airway passengers from a specific city have a body weight (in kilograms) that can be considered to have a normal distribution, with $\mu=81$ and $\sigma=3.5$. What is the probability that $21$ such passengers weigh more than $1740$ kg together? The weight of these $21$ passengers are independent from each other.
My solution to problem 1:
$3X $ -> $ c=3$
$N(3 * 3, \sqrt{3^2 * 4^2}) = N(9, \sqrt{144})$ <-- Here, I square the constant $3$
$3X + Y = N(9 + 1, 3^2 + \sqrt{144}) = N(10, \sqrt{153})$ <-- This is correct according to the book.
My solution to problem 2:
$X\in N(81, 3.5)$
$21 X = N(21 * 81, \sqrt{21^2 * 3.5^2}) = N(1701, 525)$ <-- This is incorrect according to the book! Apparently, squaring $21$ is wrong...
Instead, the book wants me to do this:
$N(21 * 81, \sqrt{21 * 3.5^2})$
By the end of the calculation, the probability turns out to be $0.75$%

Could someone please explain to me why we would square the constant only in the first problem?

The sum of 21 Normal random variables is not the same as 21 times a single random variable.
The intuition is that the "deviations" tend to cancel out when you do the sum as opposed to when you just multiply by a constan. Variance of the sum of $n$ iid random variables is $n$, not $n^2$, that of one.
